# Consume REST request from controller action in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, amazon-web-services

I need to consume a REST request within a an Update action in a controller.  This is the Amazon Payments Marketplace API.  The following is their example.  How would I call this within the controller and handle the response?  Below is also the response.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
Sample REST Request

https://fps.sandbox.amazonaws.com?
Action=Settle
&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
&ReserveTransactionId=14GKD9GE66FAA63E6O6B2JDPZKN53LZ7F22
&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256
&SignatureVersion=2
&Signature=SJJLsIBghi7VIycBjX7c3hnfgZ%2FBvZbzqLtAZXDL8ys%3D
&Timestamp=2009-10-06T07%3A53%3A11.750Z
&TransactionAmount.CurrencyCode=USD
&TransactionAmount.Value=1
&Version=2008-09-17
```

Sample Response to REST Request

```
<SettleResponse xmlns="http://fps.amazonaws.com/doc/2008-09-17/">
  <SettleResult>
    <TransactionId>14GKD9GE66FAA63E6O6B2JDPZKN53LZ7F22</TransactionId>
    <TransactionStatus>Pending</TransactionStatus>
  </SettleResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>9ed2008b-b230-4ed0-9210-095f77fc2359:0</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</SettleResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this directly with [`Net::HTTP`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html), which is bundled with ruby:

```
require "net/http"
require "open-uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

Then get the body of the response:

```
body = response.body
#=> "<!doctype html><html itemscope=\"itemscope\" ...
```

If you want to do anything more sophisticated, I'd suggest using an [HTTP client gem](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients) like [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or [faraday](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/faraday). There are a bunch of [examples using HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/examples) which include an example with [aaws](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/aaws.rb).

If the heavy lifting is only going to be on the response parsing side of things, you could use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) for that:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTTP(body)
doc.search('h1').text
#=> "Google"
```